# k-fold cross validation to tune regressive tree model using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, decision-tree, k-fold

I'm trying to use k-fold cross-validation to tune a regressive tree generated in pyspark. However, from what I've seen so far, it is not possible to combine pyspark's CrossValidator with pyspark's DecisionTree.trainRegressor. Here is the relevant code.

```
    (trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])

    model = DecisionTree.trainRegressor(trainingData, categoricalFeaturesInfo={}, impurity='variance', maxDepth=5, maxBins=32)
```

How do I then apply the k-fold cross-validation to the regressor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
(trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])

model = DecisionTree.trainRegressor(trainingData, categoricalFeaturesInfo={}, impurity='variance', numClasses=2)

paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder() \
    .addGrid(model.maxDepth, [4, 5, 6, 7]) \
    .addGrid(model.maxBins, [24, 28, 32, 36]) \
    .build()

crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=model,
                          estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                          evaluator=BinaryClassificationEvaluator(),
                          numFolds=3)  

# Run cross-validation, and choose the best set of parameters.
cvModel = crossval.fit(training)
```